# Problema ao tentar fazer requisição HTTP em Java

Tags: php, java, web-service

estou com uma problema e gostaria que vocês me ajudassem a resolver. Criei uma aplicação em java pra consumir um webservice que fiz em php. Depois de muito pesquisar consegui criar uma classe capaz de fazer requisições http. O problema é que estou me deparando com um erro com a url que estou utilizando para acessar o webservice. A classe WebClient é responsável por fazer a conexão com o webservice e retornar uma resposta (que seria uma string no formato JSON), ela recebe os dados (também uma string em formato JSON) e tenta fazer a requisição com o servidor onde o webservice ta hospedado. No entanto estou me deparando com um erro de mal formação na url. Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Classe WebClient

```
public class WebClient {
public String post(String json) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("localhost/CWS/cadastrar_guia.php");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");


        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        output.println(json);

        connection.connect();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
        String resposta = scanner.next();
        return resposta;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

No Main

```
    String guia = "{\"nome\":\"NomeUsuario\",\"sobrenome\":\"SobrenomeUsuario\",\"cpf\":\"99999999999\",\"email\":\"usuario@email.com.br\",\"senha\":\"00000\"}";
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    resposta =  wc.post(guia);

    System.out.println(resposta);
```

Erro:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: localhost//CitourWS//cadastrar_guia.php
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at webservice.WebClient.post(WebClient.java:13)
at Main.main(Main.java:76)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente a exceção  é devida a falta de partes da sua URL declarada.

Troque:

`URL url = new URL("localhost/CWS/cadastrar_guia.php");`

Por:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost/CWS/cadastrar_guia.php");
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho aqui. Muito Obrigado!